# What's the best way to add a column to an existing dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, merge, dataset

I have two extremely long queries that I am running on multiple tables, using an INNER JOIN. The only difference between these two queries is that they take different input values for one of the WHERE clauses, which they get from two separate DropDownLists. The results of these queries are identical, save for the time1/time2 columns.

```
string query1 = "select Name = t1.name, time1=(SELECT hours FROM table3 WHERE street=list1.selectedvalue), t2.address from [table1] t1 INNER JOIN [table2] t2 ON t1.param = t2.param ORDER BY Name";

string query2 = "select Name = t1.name, time1=(SELECT hours FROM table3 WHERE street=list2.selectedvalue), t2.address from [table1] t1 INNER JOIN [table2] t2 ON t1.param = t2.param ORDER BY Name";
```

(Please don't bother with the syntax of the queries above, I have executed the queries and they both return the expected results.)

I would like to merge these two tables into a single dataset (or any other structure than can be used as a datasource for a gridview). The 'name' column is unique, some others might be too, I can check. I want the final table columns to resemble

Name     Time1    Time2     Analysis    Address

- The order of the columns doesn't matter very much, but if it's not too much work, I would prefer the order above.
- I would like to carry out mathematical operations on time1 and time2, and accordingly update the analysis column. Am I better off doing this in C# or JS?

Currently, I am using a datatable to collect the results of the two queries. I tried using the Datatable.Merge method, but that actually doubles the number of rows (kind of like an outer join) in spite of naming the columns the same (in the columns.Add(new DataColumn...)

```
            Datatable dt1 = new datatable;
            Datatable dt2 = new datatable;

            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("time1", typeof(int)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("time2", typeof(int)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("analysis", typeof(string)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("address", typeof(string)));

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DataRow drow = new DataRow();
                drow["name"] = dr["name"].ToString();
                drow["time1"] = dr["time1"];
                drow["address"] = dr["CurrentTime"].ToString();
                dt1.Rows.Add(drow);
            }
            dr.Close();

            dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DataRow drow = new DataRow();
                drow["time2"] = dr["time1"];
                drow["analysis"] = "I need javascript here";
                dt2.Rows.Add(drow);
            }
            dr.Close();

            dt1.Merge (dt2);
            this.GridView1.DataSource = dt1;
            this.GridView1.DataBind;
```

Comment: Is there some common data between the tables that creates an inner join condition? How do you know which rows of 'str1' should get merged to which rows of 'str2'?

Comment: May be you try setting the missing schema action with the merge function to avoid outer join behavior.

Comment: Hi Lazy Bob, the 'name' fields in the two queries are unique for each row, and are the basis of the match for the two values of 'hours'

Comment: Have a look at this url: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313540

Comment: In order to make sure that merge method works properly you need to add schema information to the dataset. Did you do that?

Comment: d'oh! no i didn't, thanks J. okay so I need to add schema info to *both* tables, and the merge will work fine correct? what about my extra 'analysis' column?